# How to quickly type underscore?

Tags: speed, typing

I'm using gtk, and all the function names have many underscores. It gets annoying to type things like `set_from_file` and `on_button_clicked`, etc. Do you have any tips on how to type these more effectively?

Comment: For the fastest underscore possible, you could swap the space bar and the underscore keys.

Comment: Or remap shift+space to _ ?

Comment: @Nosredna - I was going to suggest that :)

Comment: This is a legitimate question people. I know vote to close is exciting but try to calm those itchy fingers. :P If this gets closed I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: If only so much attention were spent on my more legit questions about GTK.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question, but I figured that with 4 votes already it was going to get closed one way or another, so I voted to migrate to SU. I'd rather see it wind up here than being the subject of open/close wars on SO. (And I guess it's not *really* programming-related...)

Comment: well it caused me to get an account here, anyway.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using? On a standard UK/Irish keyboard, underscore is Shift+-, which isn't *too* tricky.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an editor with auto-complete functionality?

Comment: I agree. A decent editor will auto-complete for you.

Comment: most sane, probably. i'd first have to find a good one for python (IDLE works, but it is shoddy, and it only works if you run your code in it), and then get used to it. but could be worth it!

Comment: Hmm, I think swapping the underscore and spacebar keys is more efficient. :)

Comment: probs best answer, still have to find a good one for python though

Comment: Komodo edit 7 is pretty good with python!

Comment: best advice, vs code has a great extension that let's you change case based on most common styles easily https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-change-case

Answer (score 12):

Using a programmable [foot pedal](http://www.fentek-ind.com/FootPedal.htm) could help you out a bit.

Comment: You combine the chance to become a professional gtk programmer with the chance to become a death metal drummer.

Comment: haha. that'd be awesome.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but it sure made me laugh :] There was a 'computer stupidity' http://www.rinkworks.com/stupid/cs_mice.shtml about mouse/foot pedal (beware, very addictive website).

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with holding shift with your left hand and using your pinky from your right hand? That's what I do -- it's probably the fastest once you get used to touch typing it.

Comment: hmmmm... i'm using my ring finger to hit it, atm. i'll try adjusting to using a pinky and - starting now - I'll see - just = how_ ti_ goes_. i might like this.

Comment: You do have to pivot the hand a bit but you can pivot it right back __ _ __ __ __ weeeeee

Answer (score 3):

remap - key to _ so you don't have to relearn key location but can save time not hitting shift.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MSKLC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8be579aa-780d-4253-9e0a-e17e51db2223&DisplayLang=en) .. I'd remap ' (dagger) to _ and _ to '.

Answer (score 3):

Remap a **useless key** to `_`. The **most useless keys on the keyboard** are `insert` and `caps lock`. They are close to the useful keyfield, so you **might actually gain speed** once you've learned the position of your new `_` key.

Backstory: I realized that I **never** used `insert` or `caps lock`. But every so often I would hit one *by accident*. These keys are *toggles*, which affect every subsequent keystroke. Whenever I realized that I hit `insert`, I had to turn it off and then recover the text that I overtyped. Whenever I realized that I hit `caps lock`, I had to turn it off and then retype the text that I entered in "oppositecase". I found this so unacceptably frustrating (unfuriating) that I pried `insert` and `caps lock` off every keyboard that I use. It's much better that way. (I can toggle either one, when rarely needed, by reaching into the hole with the back of a pen.) (If you remap one of these keys, you can remap some other combination to replace it, or use "Onscreen keyboard".)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)

Include a configuration like:

```
a::_
```

in this case, when you type "a", it will put a "_"

Comment: I'd give the example using another key...

Comment: Of course, it's your choice wh_t you want to repl_ce

Comment: The ` is a good choice. I never use that thing. And it's pretty easy to hit. Makes your left pinky super-strong.

Comment: @samuelcarrijo, e::_

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn on capslock.
2. Place something heavy on the shift key.
3. Everything you type will be in lowercase, but if you type a - it will be a _

Alternate Method:

Use an autohotkey script

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class gtk ; or whatever the title for the window is

;Choose one of the below
-::Send _        ; replace -'s with _'s
+space::Send _   ; replace shift+space with _'s
f3::Send _       ; replace F3 with _'s. You get the idea
```

Comment: +0.4 for creativity. Unfortunately we round down.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the underscore key isn't much harder than hitting any upper case letter, since it's just a key combined with Shift.

You can always copy it to the clipboard and type Control-V if your fingers have a problem hitting the numeric row consistently.

Comment: i actually often CTRL+C annoying letters when i have to type them a lot in a particular section of code

Comment: Except that it's keyboard position puts it out of reach of all but those with abnormally long and dextrous pinkies, which means your fingers have to leave the home keys.  That significantly reduces typing speed.  It makes a difference in any application of real size.

Answer (score 1):

Practice, practice, practice...

The kids (and I) like this [Typing Instructor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832312063)

-JFV

Comment: i can already type at like 140wpm; i don't know if that typing instructor is for me

Comment: The best typing tutor is The Typing of The Dead

Comment: I learned from Mario Teaches Typing. If you got a good typing streak going, Mario blew though goombas like a samurai.

Answer (score 1):

Add a second keyboard. (You can have up to [at least 14] USB keyboards.) You could use the second keyboard directly -- but it merely types the same characters. You could tape down `Shift` on the second keyboard -- but you still have to find its `-`/`_` key every time; no time saved. With more work, you can remap keys on the extra keyboard. For example: place the second keyboard above the first one and make its `spacebar` type `_`, hitting the other spacebar **might actually be faster** than typing Shift+`-`/`_`. (And you have ~94 more keys that you can relabel for other added functions.) Recoding the second keyboard has been done using LuaMacros: https://www.diyphotography.net/create-entire-new-keyboard-shortcodes-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

Change to hungarian keyboard layout. It will be easier to write underscore as the dash will be next to the shift key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems easier to press two keys with one finger of the left and one finger of the right hand instead of two fingers of the left hand.